# IID discrete but not a.s. equal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Based on this: [Equal in distribution but unequal almost everywhere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999841)

My answer to questions like those is usually

> Flip a fair coin. $1_H$ and $1_T$ have the same distribution but are never equal.

I didn't consider that independence could make a difference. Okay so if $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, independent in a finite sample space, what's a simple example to say that they aren't a.s. equal? What about for countably infinite sample space? What about uncountable sample space but RVs still discrete?

I have a feeling I'm missing some simple example to do with flipping a coin or rolling a die.

---

Related:

[$X$ and $Y$ are defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$? Can they have different CDFs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2596665)

[Random variables defined on the same probability space with different distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578323/)

[If two random variables have CDFs that have the same value for all x, can we assume the random variables are equal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746337)

[If X and Y are equal almost surely, then they have the same distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435486)

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ and $Y$ are iid then the existence of some $x\in\mathbb R$ with $P(X=x)>0$ already excludes that $X\neq Y$ a.s.

This because: $$P(X=Y)\geq P(X=x\wedge Y=x)=P(X=x)P(Y=x)=P(X=x)^2>0$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. Further suppose $X$ is not almost surely constant; then there exists an number $c$ so that $0<P(X\le c)<1$. Then
$$
P(X\neq Y)\ge P(X\le c)P(Y>c)=P(X\le c)(1-P(X\le c))>0,
$$
so that it is not true that $X=Y$ a.s.

Comment: I suspect the OP is looking for $X,Y$ iid together with $X\neq Y$ a.s. under specific conditions.